# Find groups containing 6 consecutive 1s in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have a table with 2 columns:

- `val` with values: 0 or 1
- `id` with unique identifiers

```sql
with cte(val, id) as (
    select 0, 0 union all
    select 1, 1 union all
    select 1, 2 union all
    select 0, 3 union all
    select 1, 4 union all
    select 1, 5 union all
    select 1, 6 union all
    select 1, 7 union all
    select 1, 8 union all
    select 1, 9 union all
    select 1, 10
)
select *
into #tmp
from cte
```

How do I to find id with 6 values = 1 in a row.

In the example above: id = 9, id = 10.

It is desirable not to use loops (cursors or while), but something like `sum(...) over(...)`.

Comment: Look into the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: logic of getting id 9 and 10??

Comment: Query results have no implicit order. I assume you want to order results by `ID` and then find the *island* of 6 consecutive 1s. This type of problem is called a `gaps and islands` problem. You need to find the islands of `1`s and then select only the islands whose count is 6

Comment: Larnu, thank you. "Having" doesn't look behind on 5 steps. It always get everything. Zaynul Abadin Tuhin, logic is to find the island using the term of Panagiotis Kanavos: that is to get max(id) from the 6 "1s" going in consequence. Consiquense is set by id column (ascending order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use running sum over a window frame that contains exactly 6 rows (5 prior plus current row):

```
with cte as (
    select *, sum(val) over (
        order by id
        rows between 5 preceding and current row
    ) as rsum
    from #tmp
)
select *
from cte
where rsum = 6
```

Adjust the size of the window and where clause to match the desired value.

Answer (score 3):

Why not `LAG()` (but you need an order column):

```
SELECT id
FROM (
   SELECT 
      id,
      val,
      val1 = LAG(val, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id),
      val2 = LAG(val, 2) OVER (ORDER BY id),
      val3 = LAG(val, 3) OVER (ORDER BY id),
      val4 = LAG(val, 4) OVER (ORDER BY id),
      val5 = LAG(val, 5) OVER (ORDER BY id)
   FROM YourTable
) t
WHERE val = 1 AND val1 = 1 AND val2 = 1 AND val3 = 1 AND val4 = 1 AND val5 = 1
```

Comment: Zhorov, thank you very much. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: What if he needs a count of 7 (or anything else) in stead of 6. Is this solution easy to adapt for that ?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is using ROW_NUMBER on the LAG values

```
declare @tmp table (val int, id int)
insert into @tmp values  
(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 10)

select 0, 0 union all 
select 1, 1 union all 
select 1, 2 union all 
select 0, 3 union all 
select 1, 4 union all 
select 1, 5 union all 
select 1, 6 union all 
select 1, 7 union all 
select 1, 8 union all 
select 1, 9 union all 
select 1, 10

select t2.id,
       t2.islandcount
from   ( select t.id,
                t.val,
                t.priorval,
                row_number() over (partition by t.val, t.priorval order by t.id) as islandcount
         from   ( select id,
                         val,
                         lag(val, 1) over (order by id) priorval
                  from   @tmp
                ) t
       ) t2 
where  t2.islandcount >= 6
```

the result is

```
id  islandcount
9   6
10  7
```

Try it yourself [in this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=62950f8aa9a8f626f1bb27475317f630)

The advantage of this method is that you can easy set the value from 6 to any other value

**EDIT**

As @Zhorov mentioned in the comment, there is a flaw in my code, it returns the wrong results when you add certain rows

This solution will fix that, it is based on the solution of @SalmanA so the credit for accepted answer should go to him

```
declare @tmp table (val int, id int)
insert into @tmp values  
(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 10)

-- these are the certains rows added
,(0, 11), (1, 12), (1, 13)


select t.id,
       t.val,
       t.islandcount
from   ( select id,
                val,
                sum(val) over (order by id rows between 5 preceding and current row) as islandcount
         from   @tmp
       ) t
where  t.islandcount >= 6
order by t.id
```

And again [a DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3adc657d576ce32428b776cf3d545565)

Comment: GuidoG, thank you for the great solution.

Comment: @GuidoG, using island and gaps approach is an option, but can you check your statement again? If you add three rows (`(0, 11), (1, 12) and (1, 13))` the results are wrong.

Comment: @Zhorov Yes you are right, I was a bit too quick with this answer, I have edited my answer and added another solution. Thank you for noticing and alerting me